# Is it possible to do a toner override on the HP 3550 Laserjet?

Tags: toner

Am out of Cyan toner and need to print black only for a while. I've seen toner override instructions for other HP printers but they don't seem to apply to the HP3550.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how (and if) you can do an override on this one, but there is another trick that might be of use to you (works with many Laserjets).

First set your printer-driver to black/greyscale only.

Then pull the empty cartridge from the printer and give it a couple of hard knocks to loose any stuck toner and give it a vigorous shake.
It's quite common for an empty cartridge to still have a bit toner left, but the remains are stuck (due to static or moisture) to the insides.

Put the cartridge back in the printer.
With a little bit of luck the printer will now detect the cartridge as just nearly empty in stead of completely empty and will allow you to start a Black&White print-job.